# Apache alias for all URLs except index.php

Tags: server, apache2, php

I have two folders on the server.

```
/var/www/core
/var/www/instances/first
```

An entry point for each instance is located under the path `/var/www/instances/first`. There are

- `index.php` file
- `config.php` file
- `uploads/` folder

So at first server has to open `index.php` file and then forward all requests to another folder `/var/www/core`.
`index.php` content

```
// ... some code ... 
require '../../core/index.php';
```

As I understand I have to use Alias for reaching the goal. I have the following virtual host config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName first.com
ServerAlias www.first.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/instances/first/

Alias /uploads /var/www/instances/first/uploads/

<Directory /var/www/instances/first/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias / /var/www/core/

<Directory /var/www/core/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Redirect from www to non-www
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But with this config all my URLs (including first `index.php`) is forwarded to **core** folder. 
Maybe someone know how to change the config to prevent "aliasing" main `index.php` file.

P.s.: another alias for `uploads/` folder is needed and it is working well.

Comment: Hi @alexander.  Your config states `Alias / /var/www/core/`, this redirects your web root directory to `/var/www/core/`. Any incoming request will be redirected effectively bypassing the `/index.php` and jumping straight to `/var/www/core/`.  Is this intentional?

Comment: Hi @ThatGuy 
I have to redirect all requests except `index.php` that is still in `DocumentRoot` folder. The reason is that there is at least loading of valid configuration file (in `index.php`). Maybe this Alias `"/"` is not valid in my case. I guess I have to rewrite it to something like `"all URLs except index.php"`.

Comment: So am I right in assuming that you want incoming requests to read `/var/www/instances/first/index.php` first, then be redirected to `/var/www/core/` afterwards?

Comment: Yes @ThatGuy, you are completely right. The flow is: load `index.php` from the `instances` folder, load valid config and then require `index.php` from another folder and handle the request. And the same procedure for any requests except requests to `uploads` folder (there is a valid alias for these purposes already)

Comment: I'm not great at rewrites, but maybe something like this might work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14090483/rewrite-urls-internally-between-folders-except-for-index-php#14090562

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll take a lookt at that, but maybe it can be resolved with Aliases. Because I've resolved the same task on Nginx with aliases so I hope that I'll find something similar on Apache. Still finding the working solution...

Comment: No problems, good luck.  PS. Might be an idea to move this question to StackOverflow, as it's not directly related to Ubuntu, but Apache.  Cheers!